# Minecraft login issues

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I know I've found an answer already on here a long time ago but for whatever reason, I can't log into my launcher or the website. I know my information is correct, and my account hasn't been hacked. (At least I hope it wasn't) The launcher error is 'Invalid Email or Password' I know it had to do with a certain file but I just can't remember what file it was. If anyone can help me or find the post please do as it will really lower some of my stress levels. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Username and Password not recognized when logging into Minecraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/118282/username-and-password-not-recognized-when-logging-into-minecraft)

Answer (score 2):

If you can't log into the website either, it's unlikely a local file could affect that.

Mojang is known ([1](https://www.reddit.com/r/Minecraft/comments/3d5x7s/help_how_long_does_mojang_block_an_ip_after/), [2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/259397)) to block login attempts/throttle them after several failed logins. It's possible you failed your login a few times (due to something like a typo) and are being IP blocked since then. Double check your entered credentials (including things like caps lock and/or num lock) and try again in about 30 minutes.

You can always [reset your password](https://www.minecraft.net/en-us/password/forgot/) if needed be.

If you're concerned whether your account has been hacked, you should check your email address on [Have I Been Pwned](https://haveibeenpwned.com/). It's a reputable website that scans data breaches and logs emails found in them. If you email turns out to be in a data breach, consider changing your passwords.